# Show a subview immediately / wait until a view is visible before continuing

Tags: ios

I have an app that launches to a tab bar controller. When the app either starts up or returns from the background it checks a server for updates to its data. If updates are available, it can take several seconds to get the data and update it.

I would like to simply present an overlay view saying to the user that the app's data is updating and to please wait for a few seconds. The way that I am trying to do this is as follows: in my class that takes care of the updates I have:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[delegate.tabBarController.selectedViewController.view addSubview:updatingDataView];
[self runUpdateMethods];
```

The problem is that the updatingDataView appears on screen only after the update methods have completed. How can I get it to appear before the updating methods start?

Comment: Are the update methods performing their work on a background thread, or do they block the main thread?

Comment: Currently they block the main thread, I would like to keep it that way if possible.

Comment: There is no way to run them on the main thread while remaining responsive. You should do the work on a background thread as suggested by the answer(s) below.

Comment: That may be the best solution in the end, but would there be a way to wait until the the subview is visible before starting the update methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to empty into your run loop so that the views you've added will get drawn on the screen.  Drawing on iOs is not done real time.  You basically set up your drawing and exit your method, and the run loop actually draws it.  So what you need to do is delay the execution of runUpdateMethods until after you've exited your routine.  Try instead:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(runUpdateMethods) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this was basically what I was looking for. Now that I've had some feedback I realize that it may be smarter for me to run the update methods in another thread, but I'll try this solution to see if it works for me.

Comment: I believe `performSelector:` still runs on the calling thread see the docs of NSObject - "This method sets up a timer to perform the aSelector message on the current thread’s run loop." This will still block the UI. You would want to use `performSelectorInBackground:` instead.

Comment: Yes.  This will block his main thread, which is what he wanted to do.  He could also push a modal view and dismiss it when he's done.

Comment: I think this is the most accurate answer to my question so I'm marking it correct. But after the feedback from my question, I think that Joe's answer is a better way to accomplish what I actually wanted to do in my app, and it's the one I ended up using.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you are running `[self runUpdateMethods];` on the main thread (This will block your UI from updating). You would want to run this on a background thread. Something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0),
               ^{
                   [self runUpdateMethods];
               });
```

or

`[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(runUpdateMethods) withObject:nil];`

**Update**

Since you want to do something after `[self runUpdateMethods];` completes you would want to do something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), 
^{
    [self runUpdateMethods];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self doSomethingAfterUpdate];
    });    
});
```

Doing it this way would still give you the ability to know when `runUpdateMethods` returns and will not hang the UI.

Answer (score 2):

Your update method (the connection) is probably being executed on the Main Thread, what blocks  UI updates. You should use async methods (gcd, NSThread, NSOperationQueue, etc) to run your update.